# Python + Kivy Video on Raspbian does not work

Tags: python, video, kivy, raspberry-pi3

i have a Problem with the Video Lib. from Kivy. I'd like to run an mp4 File on my Raspberry Pi in the Kivy GUI. But its not working. I tried Windows 10 IoT as well but everytime i press NEW Python File the Visual Studio Programm crashes. Its actually insane how hard it is to make a Python Programm work on another Device. Anyone fixed the Problem with the Kivy Video ?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.video import Video

from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        video = Video(source='videoFile.mp4')
        video.state='play'
        video.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        video.allow_stretch=True
        return video

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You have an unclosed string at least where you have copied it here - `video = Video(source=videoFile.mp4')` should be `video = Video(source='videoFile.mp4')`

Comment: Well, i renamed the Path in the Browser and made the mistake there. But thanks for the comment i fixed it. Thus the Programm runs fine on Windows 10. On the Raspberry Pi i just get a white Screen.